# MaxRetryError with OAuth on Locust

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, load-testing, locust

I have my Locust file as below

```
from locust import HttpUser, TaskSet, task
import urllib.parse
from locust.env import Environment
import json

class RecommenderTasks(TaskSet):
    def on_start(self):
        self.login()
        
    def login(self):
        cold_start_url = "https://my-url.com"
        url=urllib.parse.urljoin(cold_start_url, "/oauth/token")
        payload_headers = {'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
                            'Authorization': 'Basic c2ItZGV2IXQ1Nzc6TU01U0poMUtGZ3lnR1c4dXJPcUdzREhrMTVNPQ=='}
        response = self.client.post(url, payload_headers)
        
        print(response.text)
        access_token = json.loads(response.text.encode('utf8'))['access_token']
        return access_token

    @task
    def test_recommender_multiple_platforms(self):
        self.client.get("/recommendations")

class RecommenderUser(HttpUser):
    tasks = [RecommenderTasks]
    min_wait = 1000
    max_wait = 2000

    host = "https://my-url.com"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    env = Environment(user_classes=[RecommenderUser])
    user = RecommenderUser(env)
    user.run()
```

I am trying to do an OAuth with my URL and getting an error as below

> MaxRetryError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='my-url.com', port=443): Max
> retries exceeded with url: /oauth/token (Caused by
> NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at
> 0x0000019122582C08>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno
> 11001] getaddrinfo failed'))")

Am I doing something wrong here while calling the POST method?

Answer (score 1):

It's not to the point where it's trying and failing to POST to login. It can't find your host you're trying to hit. Make sure you can hit your url from the machine you're trying to run Locust from.

Also, as a side note, you don't need to give the client requests parsed URLs, you can just pass in a string like `cold_start_url + '/oauth/token'`.